# Which dry malt extract for which type of beer?

Tags: dme, shopping

I want to make a batch of Cincinnati Pale Ale with the recipe describes in the *How to brew* of John Palmer book. To do it, I need Pale Ale DME. The problem is my [homebrew shop](https://www.brouwland.com/en/our-products/brewing/malt-extracts/spraymalt/spraymalt-brewferm) only indicates the EBC value of the malt extract and not directly the type of beer.

According to this [website](https://www.beermonthclub.com/beer-style-guide-ales), an American Pale Ale have an EBC between 10 and 25. Does it mean I should take a DME with an EBC between those values?

I found, on the [website of another shop](https://www.morebeer.com/products/pale-ale-dry-malt-extract-dme.html), a pale ale malt extract with 6°L (14.5 EBC). If my shop doesn't sell 14.5 EBC dry malt extract, should I mix two different DME to get this EBC?

In general, how can we choose the correct DME according to the type of beer we want to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target beer is an American pale ale which can have Carmel color variants from 5-10 SRM / 9.8-19.7 EBC.

*I'm not sure what that specific beers color is.*

Going darker will have more Carmel flavor and slightly sweeter perception.

Any extract derived from 2-row yielding the above color range is a pale malt.

Comment: So, if I correctly understand, you can mix malt extract as you want as long as you get a color between 5 and 10 SRM? A pale ale is just a question of color and the malt extract used has no influence on the taste? So, if I mix 50% of 18 EBC DME and 50% of 57 EBC DME, or if I mix 66% of 8 EBC DME and 34% of 95 EBC DME, I get the same 37 EBC DME? The color and the taste would be the same?

Comment: Extracts get thier varied color from the base malt and how long the hard boil was before they decide to condense. It's really not the same as crystalized malts but takes on some of its characters. As long as the base malt of the extract is the same you can mix and match to get the right color, but the final malt flavor my be slightly different.

Comment: The only information I have on the sheet about the DME is the EBC ; for instance : "Spraymalt of the highest quality, 18 EBC." https://www.brouwland.com/en/our-products/brewing/malt-extracts/spraymalt/spraymalt-brewferm/d/spraymalt-amber-500-g I don't know what is the base malt so I don't know if I can mix different malt extracts.

To come back on my initial question, I just saw the EBC of the Cincinnati Pale Ale is 10. So, can I mix 80% of spraymalt light (8 EBC) with 20% of spraymalt amber (18 EBC)?

Comment: That product is barley malt. Most likely 2-row

Comment: Thanks! But where did you find this information? How can I know, on this kind of website, what type of barely I am purshasing?

Comment: @Pierre source was the link brouwland link you provided. Since thier other spraymalt/dme products specify the grain type "wheat" etc you can assume the main product is barley. Also the data sheet references barley in the weight conversions.

Comment: Yes, I know it's barely but I want to know the type of barely (2-row, 6-row, Pilsner, Munich, ...) because you said I can mix malt extracts as long as the base malts are the same.

Comment: @Pierre basically anything not 2-row would warrant mention in the labeling.